# Translation files for Django project in code repository

Tags: django, repository, translation

I've translated my application in Django project. In effect I have two files:

```
django.po
django.mo
```

File with messages django.pl I place in my code repository, but what about django.mo? Should I place compiled messages or will be better to compile this file on destination system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it be better to recompile the translations on *every* destination system?

You can:

- compile at every checkout from the repository and then send the compiled on deploy
- keep the compiled in the repository

You normally need to have the compiled versions for dev/test anyway.
Which solution to use is only a matter of if you want to use more space in the repository and if your versioning system supports post-checkout hooks. If not it's a pain to remember to recompile translations at every repos update.